# Which good and representative tests/certificates could I get to assess my Esperanto knowledge?

Tags: certification

Many languages have many reputable ways to get certificates, which makes it easy for employers or schools to access the knowledge of the applicant (e.g. Cambridge and TOEFL for English, Goethe for German).

Are there currently any options to get certifications at any level of Esperanto (A1-C2 or any other scale)?

Are any of the tests for higher levels (the ones that require assessment of comprehension and speaking) available online?

Answer (score 15):

Esperanto is recognized by the CEFR (Common European Framework of References) and has been administering tests for a few years now. You can try a practice test here:

http://www.itk.hu/index.php?id=334&fomenu=322&menu=334%E2%8C%A9=ept

Lernu! has exams, but I don't know much about their quality.

Comment: Lernu! has undergone a complete remodel, and the exams were not included in the new site, so they are no longer available.

Comment: That link doesn't work anymore. Are there still such practice tests available?

Answer (score 13):

On Edukado.net you can read about the KER exam that is offered. 
Since 2008, 1800 people have taken and succeeded in the exams at these levels: 510 at B1, 543 at B2, 746 at C1.

The certificate itself is in four languages (Esperanto, angla, germana kaj franca). The testing is accredited by ALTE, The Association of Language Testers in Europe, an organization set up by the universities of Cambridge and Salamanca.

You can't take this online, as far as I've seen it. You can ask for a local organization to organize the exam for you, I think.

To prepare yourself for the exam: http://edukado.net/ekzamenoj/ker/specimenoj

http://edukado.net/ekzamenoj/ker

Comment: Only 1 person has passed A1? I guess it's because people usually progress past that before they consider bothering with an official test, especially if it involves deliberate organization.

Comment: To my knowledge, the Esperanto KER exams are only offered at B1, B2 and C1 levels.

Comment: It's the information from the webpage, you can follow the link and see for yourselves. Yes, I also assume it is because you reach a high level pretty quickly.

Comment: It turns out that this was an error on the edukado.net-page! Thank you to everyone that helped clear that up.

Answer (score 7):

The [Esperanto Association of Britain](http://www.esperanto.org.uk/index.html) offers [Exams](http://www.esperanto.org.uk/education/exams.html) in three levels for for Esperantists who speak also english.