# Kiel eltrovi mian Esperanta nivelon laŭ KER? How can I find out my Esperanto level according to CEFRL?

Tags: ker-exams, certification

I'd like to know what my level of Esperanto currently is, according to the [Common European Framework of Reference for Languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages) (CEFRL; esperante [Komuna Eŭropa Referenckadro por lingvoj (KER)](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komuna_e%C5%ADropa_referenckadro_por_lingvoj)).

I could of course sign up for an exam, but

- I don't know yet for what level I should test for
- I neither need nor want any certification, I just want to know for myself

Is there any **free or inexpensive online test** I can take instead? Preferably in a way where I don't have to test for a specific level, but where the difficulty automatically adapts to the measured skill and the estimated level is part of the result. (Kinda like [Pluralsight's "Skill IQ" assessments](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/02/06/pluralsight-stack-overflow-helping-worlds-developers-learn-new-skills/) do for IT skills.)

Comment: The itk.hu link from https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/77/1576 unfortunately doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

La retejo Edukado.net disponigas ekzemplan ekzamenon por la niveloj B1 B2 kaj C1. Iru al tiu [paĝo](https://edukado.net/ekzamenoj/ker/specimenoj) kaj klaku al la verda libro. (Se ĝi ankoraŭ troviĝas tie).

Parto de la skriba ekzameno estas korektita. Vi tiel povos kalkuli parton de viaj poentoj.

Notu ke la ekzempla ekzameno estas malnova, kaj eble ne plu bone taksas la malfacilecon kaj enhavon de nunaj ekzamenoj.